# HDF5 C++ : I need get Group list, Dataset list, Attribute list in HDF5 file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hdf5

I need get Group list, Dataset list, Attribute list in HDF5 file,
but I don't know list get function.

What is the function to get the list?

My library is HDFGROUP -  hdf5-1.8.14.

Answer (score 1):

```
for( int i = 0; i < g.getNumObjs(); i++ )
{
    memset( pStr, 0, 128 );
    g.getObjnameByIdx( i, pStr, 128 );
}
```

This Code Get names in group.
It attributes code is the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`H5Lvisit`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5L.html#Link-Visit) to recursively visit all objects in the root group. This will visit groups and datasets. Attributes are attached to groups and datasets so within your visitor, you can use [`H5Aiterate`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5A.html#Annot-Iterate) to iterate through attributes.

Comment: Thank you for letting me answer.